# Using the finite difference method for the boundary value problem with Neumann's boundary conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, algorithms

$$
\begin{cases}
  y'' = y + 8 + 3x(1 - x) \\
  y'(0) = -3 \\
  y'(1) = e - \frac{1}{e} + 3
\end{cases}
$$

I'm trying to solve boundary value problem using finite difference method but first of all I need to system of equations

$$
y'(0) = \frac{-3y_{0} + 4y_{1} - y_2}{2h} 
$$
$$
y'(1) = \frac{-3y_{N - 3} + 4y_{N - 2} - y_{N - 1}}{2h}
$$

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{-3y_{0} + 4y_{1} - y_2}{2h}  = -3\\
\frac{y_{i - 1} - 2y_i + y_{i + 1}}{h^2} = y_{i} + 8 + 3x_{i}(1 - x_{i}) \\
\frac{y_{N - 2} - 2y_{N - 1} + y_{N}}{2h} = e - \frac{1}{e} + 3
\end{cases}
$$

Did I get the right system? If so, how do I apply this method to the system?

Comment: Your setup for the right endpoint isn't right. For $y'(x_N) \approx a y_{N-2}+by_{N-1}+cy_N$ you want $a(f_0-2h f_1+2h^2 f_2)+b(f_0-h f_1+h^2/2 f_2)+cf_0=f_1+O(h^2)$ so $a+b+c=0,-2a-b=1/h,2a+b/2=0$ so $a=\frac{1}{2h},b=\frac{-4}{2h},c=\frac{3}{2h}$ resulting in $\frac{y_{N-2}-4y_{N-1}+3y_N}{2h}$. (This is a method to get second order discretization of the first derivative using only the points $x_k=kh,k=0,1,\dots,N$.)

Comment: However, this is not the usual way that this is handled in my experience. Instead people approximate the derivative using "ghost points": $y'(0) \approx \frac{y_1-y_{-1}}{2h}$ and $y'(1) \approx \frac{y_{N+1}-y_{N-1}}{2h}$ are centered second order approximations. This provides equations for the fictitious points $y_{-1},y_{N+1}$ and then you simply impose the discretized differential equation at $x_0$ and $x_N$ (which becomes expressed in terms of the values at the ghost points).

Comment: If you don't like the ghost points *per se*, you can simply solve for $y_{-1}$ and $y_{N+1}$ and then plug them into the discretized differential equation at $x_0$ and $x_N$. For example $y_{N+1}=2h y'(1)+y_{N-1}$ so when you would write $\frac{y_{N+1}-2y_N+y_{N-1}}{h^2}=y''(x_N)$ instead you write $\frac{2hy'(1)-2y_N+2y_{N-1}}{h^2}=y''(x_N)$.

Comment: First of all, thank you for finding the error
Second of all, I can't use approximation of derivative using "ghost points" becaues it's a part of the task to use this particular formulas for approximation

Comment: Fair enough. In that case then with the error fixed you're left to just solve the linear system you wrote down numerically.

Comment: By the way a nice quick-and-dirty way to check hand calculations of things like this, assuming you're not especially comfortable with CAS software like Mathematica, is to use "series for ..." on WolframAlpha. For example "series for e^(x-2h)-4e^(x-h)+3e^x at h=0" yields 2he^x + a term proportional to h^3, which is what I wanted to see. If I saw an h^2 term then I know I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "applying this method to the system... You have written down the linear system to be solved (apart from the correction mentioned by @Ian), now you just need to solve it. Your equations are
$$
-3y_0 + 4y_1-y_2 = - 6h
$$
$$
y_{i-1}-(2+h^2)y_i+y_{i+1} = 8h^2+3h^2 x_i(1-x_i), \quad i = 1, \cdots, n
$$
$$
y_{n-1}-4y_n+3y_{n+1} = 2h (e-e^{-1}+3)
$$

so, apart from the first and last lines, you have a tridiagonal system. Below you can visualize the numerical solution with $n=10$ (dots), compared to the exact solution $y(x)=-2 + e^{-t} + e^t - 3 t + 3 t^2$ (line).

It is also very instructive to observe the behaviour of the numerical solution when you use first order approximations of the derivatives to enforce the Neumann conditions, i.e. what happens if you replace the fisrt and last equations by $y_1-y_0=-3h$ and $y_{n+1}-y_n = h(e-e^{-1}+3)$.

[image]